# setup passenger with nginx on debian-10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, debian-buster

i started my new server-installation with debian-10.

nginx works fine, installed by `apt install nginx-full`
but then, wanted to install passenger, on that way https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/stretch/ (buster isnt listed), and i could not get it to run.

```
1) sudo apt-get install -y dirmngr gnupg
2) sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-3) keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
3) sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Add our APT repository
4) sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-5) binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger stretch main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
5) sudo apt-get update

# Install Passenger + Nginx module
6) sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

=> on step 5, the result is:

```
root@33041:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://debian.ethz.ch/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://debian.ethz.ch/debian buster-updates InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                                          
Ign:4 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger stretch InRelease                                    
Hit:5 https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger stretch Release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@33041:/#
```

and on step 6, result:

```
root@33041:/etc/apt# apt install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: passenger (= 1:6.0.2-1~stretch1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: nginx-common (< 1.10.4) but 1.14.2-2+deb10u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@33041:/etc/apt#
```

=> then, i tried

```
apt install passenger
```

=> and earned:

```
root@33041:/etc/apt# apt install passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 passenger : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
             Recommends: passenger-doc (= 1:6.0.2-1~stretch1) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: passenger-dev (= 1:6.0.2-1~stretch1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@33041:/etc/apt#
```

Questions:

a) had someone nginx and passenger brought to run on debian-10?
(i don't want to recompile nginx from source, like [this](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_rvm/))

b) if not, what are other, recommended ways (nginx as proxy to puma..)?

thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. Phusion Stretch repo conflicts with native buster packages, and Phusion Buster repo seems to be empty.

I have issued a bug here, with no reply for the moment :
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2221

Answer (score 0):

Now, that the co-founder of passenger marked Ennder's ticket, I think, they will deliver in the next time.

For me, I could not wait.

I did, what I previously avoided to do:
removed the system-installed NGINX and recompiled it from source, following [this](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/tarball/).

You end up with an NGINX under /opt/, and serve it by

```
`nginx -s reload``, ``nginx -s start`, and so on.
```

It ran fine, and it's not a bad solution. Just, configurations are very different to the usual, especially for php-fpm.

So, the aim of this ticket was solved, but, I had a lot of other problems: bringing nokogiri (Rails) to run, and, I can not say why - in one user the mysql2-gem was not able to connect.

So, at the and, after days of loosing time, I switched back to debian-9, and installations are working, nearly on the first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to buster was really awful, all my services are down, because of mysql, postgres, passenger, owncloud, radicale issues, etc.

For my part I use a lot a standalone versions so a single nginx server is not feasible.

I hope the passenger repo will be updated soon.

For your rails issues, on my side I use rbenv, to be able to control the versions of ruby I ran, not depending on OS updates.

Answer (score 0):

I learned: do not use a new Linux-release (in my case Debian) that is less than one year old.

To make our conversation complete: I use RVM, it does more, or less the same as rbenv. This was not the problem. The problem was: MariaDB had an issue so that it could not connect to the mysql2-gem. PHP could connect, but not Rails. It was a Maria-DB-issue, nearly from v10.1. So I had to change my apt-sources-list-file, that I was able to install mariaDB-10.3. Here, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 11, i had the same error on this command

```
sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

Resolved with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265236/1374865)

Answer (score 0):

I switched to puma. it's more work to configure (much more!), but runs much performanter than having ruby-on-rails behind nginx/passenger. So, nginx is the proxy, and, there's to setup a demon on user-level which runs and connects the puma.